# ASP.NET AJAX Partial Rendering

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have a question about how ASP.NET AJAX partial rendering actually works. Does it:

1) Renders the whole page on the server, transmits the whole page to the client, the client then merges just the area contained in the update panel.

2) Renders the whole page on the server, transmits and merges just the area contained by the update panel.

3) Renders, transmits and merges just the area contained by the update panel.

Thanks,

AJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 is the answer - [Partial-Page Rendering Overview](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/Documentation/Live/overview/PartialPageRenderingOverview.aspx):

> An asynchronous postback behaves much
>   like a synchronous postback. All the
>   server page life-cycle events occur,
>   and view state and form data are
>   preserved. However, in the rendering
>   phase, only the contents of the
>   UpdatePanel control are sent to the
>   browser. The rest of the page remains
>   unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which method you use. If you use an `UpdatePanel` then it is almost like a full postback, the page goes through its entire lifecycle and then just the content of the `UpdatePanel` is sent back to the browser. You could also use something like `PageMethods` to only send the data that your  method needs, and have that method return the new html that you can then place in the page (most likely in some div). This is much more efficent, but takes a little more time to setup. Check out this [link](http://encosia.com/2007/07/11/why-aspnet-ajax-updatepanels-are-dangerous/) for a comparison of `UpdatePanel` versus `PageMethods` and how to implement each.